# Facebook share functionality shows incomplete data in the comment box

Tags: asp.net, facebook, share

I want to post a link on facebook but it shows wrong data when clicking on share button but the same thing works fine in twitter sharing.

Here is the code for Twitter that works fine:

```
private void btnTweetShare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("http://twitter.com/share?url={0}",    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(URLTextBox.Text))), "_blank");
}
```

Below is the image for twitter share:
[image]

I want to share the same data on facebook,my code is also same but it post invalid data.
I am passing the data as QueryString in the Url for twitter and facebook.

```
private void btnFBShare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(URLTextBox.Text))), "_blank");
    }
```

Below image you can see the facebook share comment box contains incomplete data which is a link that i want to post.
[image]

You can see ,i want complete link to be copied but it only copies a part of it.
i.e.,
instead of showing complete value from querystring
[image]
it only shows a part of it i.e., **localhost** .

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot share something from localhost, check out what localhost is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

If you want to share something with sharer.php, it has to be an URL that is available to everyone. A real public server, with a real domain.

Also, sharer.php takes the Open Graph tags from the shared URL, here´s more about that: http://ogp.me/

Comment: @luschn.Thanks for reply.But even though i add a absolute Url path instead of localhost, it still show only a part of the string.

Comment: what url did you try?

Comment: it´s not public. every url you share on facebook needs to be public, else the facebook scraper cannot handle it correctly.